# Redis Crash Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: python, twisted, redis, celery

I’m running redis, 32bit, 2.0.2 from the cygwin compilation here: http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisWindowsDownload
I am running it from the terminal.  It works great for about 24 hours and then it crashes, no errors, it just closes.   My config file I have defaults except:

```
# save 900 1
# save 300 10
# save 60 10000
appendonly no
appendfsync no
```

I tried using a newer version of redis.  Redis-2.2.5 win32 here: https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads
However, these I can run but it throws up ‘unpacking too many values’ error when task are added onto it with Celery 2.2.6.
I haven’t ran this long enough to see if it experiences the same crashing error that 2.0.2 has after 24 hours-ish.
Also I have redis flushdb at 1am every day.  But the crash could happen any part of the day, normally around 24 hours since the last time it crashed.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

## additions

Sorry, I forgot to mention that Twisted is polling data every 20 seconds and storing it into redis, which roughly translates to close to a 700 thousand records a day or 4 or 5 gb of RAM used.  There is no problem with Twisted, I just thought it might be relevant to the question.

## follow up question?

Thanks Dhaivat Pandya!
Are there key-value database that are more supportive of the windows environment?

Comment: What does this have to do with Twisted?

Answer (score 0):

Redis does is not supposed to work with Windows, and the projects that try to make it work with windows all have numerous bugs that make them unstable.